# What Islam says about feeding animals and birds?

Tags: sharia, animals

What Islam says about feeding animals such as birds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There be reward of kindness towards every living thing.

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "While a man was walking on a road. he
> became very thirsty. Then he came across a well, got down into it,
> drank (of its water) and then came out. Meanwhile he saw a dog panting
> and licking mud because of excessive thirst. The man said to himself
> "This dog is suffering from the same state of thirst as I did." So he
> went down the well (again) and filled his shoe (with water) and held
> it in his mouth and watered the dog. Allah thanked him for that deed
> and forgave him." The people asked, "O Allah's Messenger (ﷺ)! Is there
> a reward for us in serving the animals?" He said, "(Yes) There is a
> reward for serving any animate (living being) ."
>
> https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/40

> The Prophet (ﷺ) said, "If any Muslim plants any plant and a human
> being or an animal eats of it, he will be rewarded as if he had given
> that much in charity."
>
> https://sunnah.com/bukhari/78/43