# Is it a good deed to feed cats

Tags: animals

Is it a good deed to feed stray cats and will it add to my good deeds in the day of judgement or is it something normal

Comment: Feeding animals is regarded as act of good in Islam... but make sure what feed them is good and healthy for them. Also be aware, that if you feed them regularly they won't be stray any more but tend to hang around your place more often :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What Islam says about feeding animals and birds?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/63044/what-islam-says-about-feeding-birds)

Comment: Thx bro . I guess they were stray but know they are mine lol as they stay in my house . I give them left over chicken and some milk mixed with water .